# Map reading from text file directx

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, directx, text-files

This is an example of my code, I have a notepad file which has letters and for each letter I want to be able to spawn a different model when the scene has been loaded. Effectively if done right I could make a map builder within the map using picking but at this stage this is off topic. This code has been taken from a previous project which was a win32 console project which used the map reading to generate path finding, I have initialized the models above under the class CModel, which handles the loading into scene e.g geometry and the skin for the model but how could I change this code to allowing me to generate these models from a text file; in directx. Help please!

```
void Map(float updateTime)
{

//=========== Reading grid from text file =========== //    

    vector<string> grid; // creating 10x10 grid.
    int count = 0;
    int row = 10;
    int col = 10;  

    ifstream input( "Map1.txt" );  //  The input file

    string line; // stores each line.
    if (input.is_open()) 
    {

       while(getline(input, line))
       {
           grid.push_back(line); // get new line.
       }
    }
    else // writes to screen if text file doesn't open.
    {
        stringstream outText;
        outText << "Not open";
        RenderText( outText.str(), 0, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
        outText.str("");
    }

    while( input && row <= 100 ) // checking each row and col for values from .txt
    {
        input >> grid[ row ][ col ];
        if( input ) 
        {
            if( ++col == 10 )
            {       
                ++row;                  
                col = 0;                
            }
        }
    }

    for(size_t i=0 ; i < grid.size(); ++i) // finding the size of each line
    {

    }

    if(line == "W") // trying to generate model from letters from the text file.
    {
        grid.push_back(new CModel* = Cube);
    }
    input.close();
}
```